# Modeling a sports tournament in Cypher using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a simple csv that has some boxing matches. I'm trying to figure out how to model this in Neo4j.

The csv looks like this:

[image]

My interest in practicing using this small dataset in Neo4j was because it seems like Neo4j would be a good way to easily query who fought who, and who had common opponents, or whatever.

My first thought was that naturally, each boxer should be represented in a 'boxer' node, and each fight should be represented in a 'fight' node.

After modeling it as such, I realized, that there *isn't* actually one node for each boxer, because over time, the boxer's age changes. So I realized that each boxer would have to have a separate node for each fight. For example, Glass Joe has 2 fights and thus he appears twice, once when he was 23 and once next year when he battled Sandman and he was 24:

[image]

But this kinda defeats the purpose. Now, my graph will be made up of disconnected sets of 3 nodes, one for each fight in the csv.  So what's the purpose?

My question is, how can I model such a simple yet complex situation like this: some type of tournament or game that changes over time, and the properties of the competitors' nodes change -- yet we want the graph to be connected:

[image]

(oops: Sandman should now be 51)

But then again, I don't think the above image is correct -- the edges shown are actually properties of the `boxer` node. If they are properties of the boxer...then they don't belong on the edge, right?

Here is my code so far (and the csv [lives here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60220533/punchout.csv)):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///<grab it from dropbox please!>' AS line
CREATE (b:boxer  {boxer_id: line.boxer_id, name: line.name})
SET b.age = TOINT(age);


LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///<grab it from dropbox please!>' AS line
MERGE(f:fight  {fight_id: line.fight_id});
```

I end up with these nodes:

[image]
[image]

...but not sure how to connect them.  Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first instinct was right.  Ideally if you had the boxer's birthday that's what you would store.  That would also help you tell apart boxers who have the same name/nickname.  Your idea of storing the boxer's age as part of the relationship is a good idea, though.

If you really wanted to store each node for each boxer for each row you could do the following:

```
(:BoxerRecord)-[:FOUGHT_IN]->(:Fight)
(:BoxerRecord)-[:REPRESENTS]->(:Boxer)
```

So basically you use the `CREATE` clause to create each `BoxerRecord` and `MERGE` for each `Boxer` record so that they get merged together.

Then if you wanted to find all of the boxers that two people have fought in common (I'm making up an :

```
MATCH
  (b1:Boxer {boxer_id: 100),
  (b2:Boxer {boxer_id: 101})
  (b1)<-[:REPRESENTS]-(:BoxerRecord)-[:FOUGHT_IN]->(:Fight)<-[:FOUGHT_IN]-(:BoxerRecord)-[:REPRESENTS]->(common_boxer:Boxer)<-[:REPRESENTS]-(:BoxerRecord)-[:FOUGHT_IN]->(:Fight)<-[:FOUGHT_IN]-(:BoxerRecord)-[:REPRESENTS]->(b2)
RETURN common_boxer, count(*)
```